# Azure API managment Policy check contain for URL

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to set variable if url contains text "verification"

```
<set-variable name="pathQuery" value="@(context.Request.Url.Contains("verification"))" />
```

I get the following error

> Error in element 'set-variable' on line 16, column 10: 'IUrl' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method
>   overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, string)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

How do I set this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the code as below:

```
<set-variable name="pathQuery" value="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("verification"))" />
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/policy-expressions-in-azure-api-management/).